# OpenMP not working in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm using Mac OS X and followed the directions here (http://hpc.sourceforge.net) to install gcc.

I have the following simple program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, 
         char **argv)
{

    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp for private(i)
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }

}
```

and compile as follows:

```
gcc -o test -fopenmp test.c
```

the result is

```
./test
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: What's wrong? At a glance, the output looks correct.

Comment: @tangrs Sorry, I'm very new to parallel computing (I actually have never tried it before), but shouldn't the outputs of `printf` not be sequential if the for loop is parallelized?

Comment: No, the order can be in any order depending on the scheduler. It happens to be sequential in your case.

Comment: @tangrs Okay, I think I see. But if I ran the for loop for, say, `i < 5000000`, I should see that the parallelized for loop takes around half as long to execute than an un-parallelized version, right?

Comment: Because they take about the same time to execute, which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: You're not running this on a single core machine are you? Also, check you're actually using gcc and not clang. I don't believe clang supports openmp at this stage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51245/discussion-between-user1799323-and-tangrs)

Comment: It should not take less time to do the loop than a single core. The simple reason is that your main (and only) task in your loop is printing information. The `printf()` has to go through a system call to print the data and that part is critical (system-wise), hence if you have one core asking to print 10,000 lines or two cores asking to print the same number, it should take roughly the same amount of time. In fact, a single core should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the program with `i < 10000000` and checked how much CPU time it was taking.

[image: 105.4% CPU 2 Threads]

You can see that two threads where indeed spawned but it's only giving the performance equivalent to one thread.

I suspect there is a lot of contention happening in the `printf` call. The library might be implementing locking in a way that each thread has to wait for an adjacent one to finish printing before it can start. In other words, only one thread can be printing at a time.

The results of the experiment above confirms this.

I.e: you're expecting this

```
| Thread 1 | Thread 2 |
| printf   | printf   |
| printf   | printf   |
| printf   | printf   |
| printf   | printf   |
| printf   | printf   |
```

when it's probably more like this

```
| Thread 1 | Thread 2 |
| printf   |          |
|          | printf   |
|          | printf   |
| printf   |          |
| printf   |          |
```

Ironically, this program runs a lot faster when compiled without OpenMP

```
$ gcc -O3 -fopenmp omp.c
$ time ./a.out > /dev/null
^C

real    0m16.743s
user    0m3.679s
sys     0m13.954s
$ gcc -O3 omp.c
$ time ./a.out > /dev/null

real    0m1.790s
user    0m1.740s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Comment: so this is weird. `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` gives an output of `4` (hyper-threading I guess) but if I run `omp_hello.c` (https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_hello.c) I get `Number of threads = 1`